# Ember - Record-specific controller properties?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Pretty new to Ember. So I understand that I can I can have controller properties for display logic.

In my template, I'm displaying a few properties for each record in the model.

```
{{#each student in model itemController="student" }}
```

I'm then using model properties such as

```
Score: {{student.score}}
```

Is it possible for me to have a controller property for the purpose of showing some display logic specific to that individual student?

Answer (score 0):

So maybe a silly question, feel free to delete. It seems I just hadn't figured out the naming conventions properly yet.

Page specific properties and actions in "student" controller.

Record specific properties and actions in the "student-items" controller. (May revise the name), and referenced in the template with

```
{{#each student in model itemController="student-items" }}
```